# Excel VBA find match and return alternating values

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble trying to include something into a macro I am building. I need it to search through column C
for cells that say "start trans" and in one column over  (d)- the first value will be equal to zero, next instance should be 100, next instance 0 next instance 100 so on until the end of the data.

Instances are not always every 4th line and I have other zeros that I want it to overlook.

Thank you for any help!

[image: Example sheet]

Comment: And what should the macro do with the rows it found? Also it looks like you just need to find all the `start trans` in Column C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one:

```
Sub GoGoGo()
Dim l As Long: Dim i As Long
Dim b As Boolean
With ActiveSheet
    l = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To l
        If .Cells(i, "C").Value2 = "start trans" Then .Cells(i, "D").Value2 = b * -100: b = Not b
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim n As Long, Result As Integer
    Set rngDB = Range("c5", Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each rng In rngDB
        If rng = "start trans" Then
            n = n + 1
            If n Mod 2 Then
                Result = 0
            Else
                Result = 100
            End If
            rng.Offset(0, 1) = Result
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for my sheet - I believe it to be because the values are not already there, it was a blank cell. I needed the macro to put them there; I should have clarified that in my original post. Thank you!